# Change UILabel to the value declared in an appDelegate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to send a value to the appDelegate from one UIViewController, so that another UIViewController can use the value and set a UILabel.text to that value.

Here's what I have so far,**the UIViewController setting the label text just sets the text to "0.00000"**. Also, the files below aren't the whole thing, just the relevant code.

**appDelegate.h**

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
id *recordedNewTime;
}
@property (nonatomic) id *recordedNewTime;
@end
```

**appDelegate.m**

```
@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize recordedNewTime;
@end
```

**HomeView.m**

```
#import "Reflex_Test_ProAppDelegate.h"
- (void)viewDidLoad
{        
    [super viewDidLoad];
    startTimer = [[NSDate alloc]init];
}

-(IBAction)stopTime
{
    // STOP TIME AND ASSIGN TIME LAPSE RESULT TO newTime
    stopTimer = [[NSDate alloc]init];
    void *newTime;
    newTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time : %f", [stopTimer timeIntervalSinceDate:startTimer]];

    // SEND newTime DATA TO APP DELEGATE FOR OTHER VIEWS TO USE
    AppDelegate *mainDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    mainDelegate.recordedNewTime = newTime;

    // SHOW NEXT VIEW
    PostSecondView *postsecondView = [[PostSecondView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:postSecondView animated:NO];

}
```

**SecondView.m**

```
#import "Reflex_Test_ProAppDelegate.h"
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    // ACCESS APP DELEGATE
    AppDelegate *mainDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    // CHANGE UILABEL TEXT ON THIS VIEW TO THE RESULT SAVED ON recordedNewTime
    newResult.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time : %f", mainDelegate.recordedNewTime]; 

}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly is the problem/question?

Comment: what is the value your getting from `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time : %f", mainDelegate.recordedNewTime];`?

Comment: I'm receiving the value of "0.000000", but I know the value isn't that as I used a debug label to show me on the first View.

Comment: recordedNewTime is an `id` type are you parsing it correctly  to float?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's why you shouldn't use `id` and `void*` if not necessary.

You save a NSString in recordedNewTime in this line:

```
newTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time : %f", [stopTimer timeIntervalSinceDate:startTimer]];
mainDelegate.recordedNewTime = newTime;
```

and later you use %f with that NSString, that won't work.

```
newResult.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time : %f", mainDelegate.recordedNewTime];
```

Try to use `newResult.text = mainDelegate.recordedNewTime;`

And please change `id recordedNewTime` to `NSString *recordedTimeString;` or something similar.

And btw `id *foo` is a pointer to a pointer to an object. Usually it is `id foo;`

Comment: I was just writing the same thing.  His variables are all confused.